# "The requested resource does not exist" - simple GET query

Tags: soql, rest-api, java

I've created an account.
How to get access to its data via REST? For example for the database or my custom objects?

Also I don't understand why when I do request with this query

```
SELECT Name, Id, CreatedBy from Account
```

I do not get any results. I thought it connects to database which is shown in schemebuilder. Was I wrong?

P.S. Could anybody explain what data can be accessed via REST? Because with my recent queries I have got unknown for me accounts, contacts. Or for example when I try to get list of contacts

```
String serviceUrl = instanceUrl + "/services/data/v31.0/v31.0/query/";
params[0] = new NameValuePair("q", "SELECT Name, Title FROM Contact");
```

I have this result

```
{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the resource you are trying to query you have appended the version number twice. try by changing the resource url to /services/data/v31.0/query